# qgis One to Many Relationship

Tags: qgis, relates

When I enter point id **1790** result join is only one input.
I won from **list** all **id_gm** to be shown in atribute table of layer **tacka6**.

Can this be done in Qgis?

[image]

Solution

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OowgI1b2ihw&feature=youtu.be

Comment: You need to set a relation in project properties, not a join in layer properties...

Comment: when i set up in project properties relations I do not get any results.

Comment: The answers offered by the administrators are quite unclear, I think this issue should be open.

Comment: but how you did it, give us screenshot

Comment: I give you video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OowgI1b2ihw&feature=youtu.be